# Debugging malloc error in C

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, free

I am currently working on a huge program written by another version. Over the last days I implemented some new features, but today I realized that this does not work correctly with some old features.

I used the lldb debugger on the program and get the following error message:

```
MT(3934,0x7fff797e3310) malloc: *** error for object 0x307400650: incorrect checksum    for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Process 3934 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x52b27, 0x00007fff92e24866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill +   10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x00007fff92e24866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10:
-> 0x7fff92e24866:  jae    0x7fff92e24870            ; __pthread_kill + 20
   0x7fff92e24868:  movq   %rax, %rdi
   0x7fff92e2486b:  jmpq   0x7fff92e21175            ; cerror_nocancel
   0x7fff92e24870:  ret
```

After moving up some levels I can see:

```
frame #6: 0x000000010000e602 MT`free_matrix(m=0x0000000307400520, nrl=1, nrh=7, ncl=1,  nch=7) + 66 at nrutil.c:282
(lldb) up
frame #7: 0x000000010000b925 MT`equations + 1221 at equations.c:619
   616          
   617          //Free memory for next round or final
   618          free_vector(B,1,n);
-> 619          free_matrix(A,1,n,1,n);
   620
```

If you want I could post the function for free_matrix(..) and the function which allocates the matrix but its basically malloc and free.

Now I definitely don't want anybody to give a solution. I am just asking how you would proceed in this case.

So my main question is: Is the error definitely tied to the matrix A or may there be other details I should search for?

Comment: "Now I definitely don't want anybody to give a solution." - I think you might be wrong here.

Comment: ? I don't use debugging that often so I do not know if the error has to be where the debugger says it is

Comment: You might like to consider running the program using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org).

Comment: The 'incorrect checksum' error probably means that some of the code in your program went trampling out of bounds, writing on memory that `malloc()` considers part of its control information rather than space you're allowed to use.  It may well be associated with your matrix manipulation; it is fairly unlikely to be a problem in `free_matrix()` itself, speaking from experience — it is just the messenger, not the cause of the problem. Since you're on Linux, use `valgrind` as suggested.

Comment: So I installed Valgrind (was not easy on OSX), but running the program now gives me a valgrind error:: valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x100030000, 8707842048) failed in UME (load_segment2)

Comment: OK valgrind runs. There were some huge static arrays in the program..